# Trouble with NFS file sharing on Synology 211 NAS and Ubuntu Client

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, synology

I'm attempting to set up NFS file sharing and keep getting the error

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.110:/myshared
```

Here is the exact command I'm using to mount:

```
sudo mount -o nolock 192.168.1.110:/myshared /home/emiller/MyShared
```

I have set 'Enabled NFS' in DSM and set NFS priviledges in the the Shares section of the control panel. Here is the `/etc/exports` entry from the NAS:

```
volume1/myshared 192.168.1.*(rw,sync,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,anonuid=0,anongid=0)
```

I read some things about the `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` but it seems like if they are empty they aren't used for anything. I can see the share when I run ...

```
showmount -e 192.168.1.110
```

Any help would be appreciated in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake on my part. Needed to put a `/` in front of

```
volume1/myshared 192.168.1.*(rw,sync,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,anonuid=0,anongid=0)
```

so that it becomes

```
/volume1/myshared 192.168.1.*(rw,sync,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,anonuid=0,anongid=0)
```